# Com.sun.media.jai.Seekablestream classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, import, codec

I have imported jai_codec-1.1.3.jar `seekablestream` in eclips.

No issue with importing `seekabkestream` class but while running tomcat server I'm getting `classnotfoundexception`

I have tried to configer jars in build path multiple times and added in class variable also still I'm getting the same issue

Please help me if anyone know what to do.

I have tried with
`Jai_coded-1.1.3.jar` and sun-`jai_codec.jar`.

Comment: Eclipse has a separate _"Java Build Path"_ and _"Deployment Assembly"_. Only the jars in the latter are copied to Tomcat, so check your deployment assembly.

Comment: Thank you so much, resolved after added the jar into deployment assembly in Eclipse.